# Azure Resource Manager DNS: Sample code to create a DNS record

Tags: azure-resource-manager, azure-sdk-.net, azure-sdk

I'm currently trying to move out from using old Microsoft.Azure.Management.Dns package to the new Azure.ResourceManager.Dns.

However I've been having issues in our code that creates Dns records such as an Arecord.

I've tried to go through the official documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.resourcemanager.dns.dnsarecordcollection.createorupdate?view=azure-dotnet

But the classes that represent an Arecord are either read only or private so I have no idea how to update this simple lines:

```
RecordSet set = DnsManagementClient.client.RecordSets.Get(resourceGroupName, zone, recordSetName, RecordType.A);
set.ARecords = set.ARecords ?? new List<ARecord>();
set.ARecords.Add(new ARecord(ipAddress));
DnsManagementClient.client.RecordSets.CreateOrUpdateWithHttpMessagesAsync(resourceGroupName, zone, recordSetName, RecordType.A, set, ifNoneMatch: "*");
```

Currently documentation only talks about Zones, can an example be added to the official documentation on how to add or update a DNS record (A,CNAME,etc..)

https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/tree/main/sdk/dns/Azure.ResourceManager.Dns

I'm expecting a method to create an A record that let's you specify an IP address, and currently all the classes that potentially can be used to do that are either read-only or internal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DnsARecordData has an internal list of Arecords, DnsARecordData.DnsARecords is where we can invoke the Add method to create the record. The reason DnsARecordData doesn't have a setter method is due to the [.Net framework design guideline.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/guidelines-for-collections#collection-properties-and-return-values).

An example of how to create an A record using Azure.Resourcemanager.Dns can be found here:

```
// Create or update A record
string myARecordName = "myrecord";
DnsARecordData dnsARecordData = new() {TtlInSeconds = (long)TimeSpan.FromHours(1).TotalSeconds};
dnsARecordData.DnsARecords.Add(new DnsARecordInfo { IPv4Address = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1") });

DnsARecordCollection dnsARecordCollection1 = dnsZoneResource.GetDnsARecords();
dnsARecordCollection1.CreateOrUpdate(WaitUntil.Completed, myARecordName, dnsARecordData);

// Create or update CName pointing to A record
string myCnameName = "mycname";
DnsCnameRecordData dnsCnameRecordData = new() { Cname = $"{myARecordName}.{DnsZone}", TtlInSeconds = (long)TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10).TotalSeconds, };
DnsCnameRecordCollection cnameRecordCollection  = dnsZoneResource.GetDnsCnameRecords();
cnameRecordCollection.CreateOrUpdate(WaitUntil.Completed, myCnameName, dnsCnameRecordData);
```

Answer (score 2):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

You can create A record set using `Azure.ResourceManager.Dns` package. The version of NuGet package is beta-1.

**NuGet Package:**

```
Azure.ResourceManager.Dns 1.0.0 beta-1
```

**Code:**

```
using Azure;
using Azure.Identity;
using Azure.ResourceManager;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Dns;
using Azure.ResourceManager.Resources;
using System.Net;


ArmClient armClient = new ArmClient(new DefaultAzureCredential());
SubscriptionResource subscription = await armClient.GetDefaultSubscriptionAsync();
// first we need to get the resource group
string rgName = "rg-name";
ResourceGroupResource resourceGroup = await subscription.GetResourceGroups().GetAsync(rgName);
string dnsZoneName = "dns name";
DnsZoneCollection dnsZoneCollection = resourceGroup.GetDnsZones();
DnsZoneData data1 = new DnsZoneData("Global")
{
};
ArmOperation<DnsZoneResource> lro = await dnsZoneCollection.CreateOrUpdateAsync(WaitUntil.Completed, dnsZoneName, data1);
DnsZoneResource dnsZone = lro.Value;
RecordSetACollection recordSetACollection = dnsZone.GetRecordSetAs();
string name = "cname1";
var parm = new ARecordSetData();
parm.TTL =600;
parm.ARecords = new List<ARecord>();
parm.ARecords.Add(new ARecord("1.2.3.4"));

ArmOperation<RecordSetAResource> recordSetAResource = recordSetACollection.CreateOrUpdate(WaitUntil.Completed, name,parm);
RecordSetAResource recordSetAs = recordSetAResource.Value;
```

**Console:**
[image]

**Portal:**

[image]

**For more reference:**

[azure-sdk-for-net/Sample2_ManagingRecordSetPtrs.md at dvbb-mgmt-track2-dns-2 · dvbb/azure-sdk-for-net (github.com)](https://github.com/dvbb/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/dvbb-mgmt-track2-dns-2/sdk/dns/Azure.ResourceManager.Dns/samples/Sample2_ManagingRecordSetPtrs.md)

Comment: This is good, thank you for the code, but please try to update IP address in the "new ARecordSetData(); parm.TTL =3600;" - it's not public (or for other record types, other similar 'core' properties)

Comment: RE: "if you need to create with IP address you can follow this" - the whole point of this question is how to use new, non-deprecated package (please see very beginning of the question)